# add_user_meta and update_user_meta working only sporadically

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display something to my wordpress site users depending on the number of times they have logged in. I've tried to accomplish this using user_meta and the wp_login hook.

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'survey_login' );
function survey_login() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $login_count = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'login_count', true);

    if($login_count == "") { $login_count = 0; }

    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, "login_count", $login_count++ );

    if($login_count >= 5) {
        $_SESSION['csm_survey_login'] = true;
    }
}
```

This seems like it should work, but for some reason the user_meta key only gets added/updated about 1/20th of the time. I've been able to find no pattern to how or why.

I've tried simplifying the function to simply

```
add_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'login_count', 1);
```

Or

```
update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'login_count', 1);
```

Both are giving me the same trouble.

**Anyone know why update_user_meta or wp_login may only work a fraction of the time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time this is loaded the meta key won't exist, if a meta key can't be found the function with return `false` not an empty string, and you can't increment `false`. Don't use `empty()` as this will return true for `0`, but to test for false instead of an empty string use:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'survey_login' );
function survey_login() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    // Get meta key, returns false if it doesn't exist
    $login_count = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'login_count', true );

    // Test for false and set to default
    if ( false === $login_count ){
        $login_count = 0;
    }

    // Increment and update
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, "login_count", ++$login_count );

    if( $login_count >= 5 ) {
        $_SESSION['csm_survey_login'] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your incrementing. `$login_count++` returns the current value of `$login_count` and then increments. You want `++$login_count` which returns the incremented value.

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'survey_login' );
function survey_login() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $login_count = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'login_count', true);

    if($login_count == "") { $login_count = 0; }

    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, "login_count", ++$login_count );

    if($login_count >= 5) {
        $_SESSION['csm_survey_login'] = true;
    }
}
```

Cheers.